# have problem about displaying html

Tags: mysql, html, coding-style, editor

I have a problem about displaying HTML using data from MySQL.

I using tinyMCE, and content will save as HTML format.

When i want to display it on my browser it displays correctly.
**BUT** is not working properly when I try to limit 400 characters

Assume this code as MySQL content which i want to display:

```
<div class="someclass" >
  this is content from MySQL
</div>
```

If limit to 20 characters, there will be no ending `</div>` and you can think what will happen without that `</div>`

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I don't understand what you're asking here...

Comment: @Marco OP wants to something like limit 40 character `<div>{40 characters} and the ending tag</div>`

Comment: We need to see the code where you're cutting off the string.

Comment: @ajreal: question is clear now, but when he asked... well, read it ;) Anyway I posted some comment that, I think, helped our mates to solve OP problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly....

you can use the php function to limit the output

```
// will display only the first 100 chars
$text = substr($desc,0,100);
```

Edit :

to preserve HTML output

http://alanwhipple.com/2011/05/25/php-truncate-string-preserving-html-tags-words/

Comment: Read my comment on Marco Johannesen's answer. Am I right? What do you think?

Comment: right then he will need something like http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7125#related

Comment: I can't give OP an answer, because I really don't understand his question. Does he just want to know how to _truncate_ text in PHP or using SQL? Maybe... anyway your answer is correct, but take care of my suggestion...

Comment: sorry if my english is bad, i know how to limit my text, im using php, but as i sad, all my data will save as HTML format in database, and when i limit data , some of html styles dont close, for example a <div> may start but when i limit data, that div may not close because of limitation and destroys!! all others styles .. sorry again if my english is bad :(

Comment: Mr Tarek, thank you so much, that truncateHtml function helped me. sorry i cant give reputation, my own rep is less than 15, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you sing for the TinyMCE?

From MYSQL you could do

`SELECT LEFT(text,400) FROM news...`

etc for limiting the characters

Comment: I think that OP could have a problem with that: if he saves HTML code in database, reading that code from db and limiting it, this could lead to html code missing closing part. Think you save `<label ...>.....</label>` or `<a href....>...</a>` but limiting you delete `</div>` or `</a>` part... your showed HTML is not correct and could lead to unpredictable behaviour if you don't manage it... Am I right? What do you think?

Comment: I can't give OP an answer, because I really don't understand his question. Does he just want to know how to _truncate_ text in PHP or using SQL? Maybe... anyway your answer is correct, but take care of my suggestion...

Comment: Agree. Bad questions leads to bad answers :P

Comment: sorry if my english is bad, i know how to limit my text, im using php, but as i sad, all my data will save as HTML format in database, and when i limit data , some of html styles dont close, for example a <div> may start but when i limit data, that div may not close because of limitation and destroys!! all others styles .. sorry again if my english is bad :(